# Failed to submit app to iTunes Store

Tags: xcode, validation, app-store, submit

I am having some problems when trying to submit my iPhone app to store using Xcode 5 that my app is always failed validation with below errors:

> Apple's web service operation was not successful
>
> Unable to authenticate the package: [My app id, ex: 123456789].itmsp
>
> ERROR ITEMS-9000: "The bundle [Bundle ID, ex: com.myapp.mobile] at bundle path 'Payload/[My App Name].app' is not signed using an Apple submission certificate." at SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset (MZItmspSoftwareAssetPackage)

I am quite sure about settings (bundle id, certificate, profile, entitlement) because this is not first time I submit app to store, jut don't know why these issues come up, I have tried to search and found some related article but they don't help.

I have this issue for 1 week.

Comment: Finally I found the reason. I thought app is identified by app id only but I was wrong. I changed the PRODUCT NAME to remove just 1 whitespace, I changed it back then problem solved.

Comment: I am having the same problem. What do you mean "PRODUCT NAME"? Where should I be looking at? Please help.

Comment: Besides, "PRODUCT NAME" has to match what?

Comment: @JoeHuang Hi Joe Huang, I only have problem with product name, change it back older name then it was ok, my app is being reviewed. You can find it in Project Settings, but if you don't change your product name then you may having another problem.

Comment: I think I got it. Your bundle ID uses the product name, so if it's not correct, the bundle ID wouldn't match, which caused the problem. But I actually had another problem that caused the error. I will share mine in the answer.

Comment: You can mark my answer as right if it helped. It worked for other ppl too, and might be of help for more users too!

Comment: I got the same issue. My bundle name was different to the product but updating $(PRODUCT_NAME) to that used in the bundle seems to have worked.

Answer (score 5):

I just selected Standard Architectures in both Project and Target, and it worked for me.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, if I wouldn't have found this answer I think I probably would have never figured this out.  The error Apple is throwing back says nothing about the application architecture being an issue.

Comment: Thanks! I tried all other things but not worked. This was the answer for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact the same error, after hours of trying, adjusting all the parameters like the bundle ID or display name, etc. None of them worked.

Finally I got it work. Here is what I did.

I started all over by deleting all the records in keychain, certificates and provision profiles. And just added one certificate and profile for app distribution. There was only one record to make no confusion. And then boom, it uploaded successfully.

I guess my mistake was to submit multiple times of certificates or provision profiles earlier (although I deleted multiple entries but I did see something strange) because I thought the creation process was stuck so I refreshed the browser. Being patient in each steps will eventually saves more time! :) Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error today with xCode 7. I resubmitted with no changes and it went through. Probably Apple bug. I am letting you know that sometimes it is not an issue with our project/target settings.

Comment: I did exactly the same thing. The second time it went through without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the cause, but I had the same exact issue crop up this week and just got things to work.  I had checked the build, distribution certificate, provisioning profile.  I went through all of the troubleshooting steps in [Technical Note TN2250](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html) -- no luck!  However, I just got it to upload successfully.  I happened to have an old Mac Mini that had Application Loader 2.5.1 on it.  I created a zip file from the .app within the Payload folder of the .ipa, put this on a USB drive, and watched as it finally uploaded after trying about 50 times with both Xcode organizer and Application Loader v2.9.

Other people have reccomended reverting to a previous Application Loader version. Perhaps the web service endpoint uses a different (and properly working) certificate validation method for older AL versions.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, this specific error is intermittent and not caused by anything in the app package.  I think many of the answers here are people that saw this error, changed something, and saw the error go away, and assumed that their change made it go away.

I would suggest, if you get this error, just try again (worked for me).  If it fails in this exact way a second time, and you have some theory about what will fix it, do that and try again.  If that works, undo your fix and see if the failure comes back.  In this way you will have proven that there was an identified root cause and a fix.

Answer (score 0):

I too have had the same problem and after many hours I managed to solve. 
I finally fixed the problem. You needed to download the "Apple Root Certificate Authority" (http://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/) and put it in your login keychain & system, I also put your iPhone disitrbution certified in your system and set all keychian trust values ​​for all certificates to "system default". Finally went through!

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was in selecting the wrong iOS distribution code signing identity, where I was using a different team as the provisioning profile.

Probably make sure your Code Signing Identity is set to automatic, which will probably fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In XCode 6.3, You have connect actual device and selected in the XCode.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see this listed on here, but I received this issue and realized that I already had a build for this specific Version # waiting for review on iTunes Connect. I rejected the build in ITC and then tried uploading the build again and it uploaded correctly after that. Just in case this could possibly help anyone else out there with this issue!