# iOS Missing or Invalid Signature: The bundle is not signed using an Apple Submission Certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, app-store-connect, code-signing-certificate

I have been trying to sign my iOS app for about a week now and when I attempt to submit to the app store through Xcode and through Application Loader I keep running into this error:

Application Loader
[image]

Xcode:
[image]

I am building the app with the Apache Cordova tools for Visual Studio and i have tried both building the .ipa file through visual studio under the 'release' setting and also using on the project files built by the 'remotebuild' tool on a mac to create a new Xcode project and then trying to archive and submit it to the app store that way.

In the Xcode situation, i have tried the solutions given in this question [Failed to submit app to iTunes Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19090640/failed-to-submit-app-to-itunes-store) and i have made sure that the bundle ID of the app matches the bundle ID of the provisioning profile.  When I run the validation and export tasks in the archive organizer they both work fine but i cannot get past this error despite that.

When i try to publish through visual studio, I am building the app with the 'release' setting so there is a .ipa file within the app's directories and then i'm transferring the files of my PC to my Mac with a flash drive, taking the newly created .ipa file, and submitting it through Application loader and it is giving me the same exact error.  Does anyone have any idea how to verify or manually sign an app with a provisioning profile or can they recommend a fix to this bug?

EDIT:
I believe I have the correct keys in my keychain

[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### I Resolved like this

1. open **KeyChain Access** application
2. Click **Login** in left-top *Keychains* section and then select **Certificates** from bottom-left *Category* section
3. Select **"Apple Worldwide Developer Certification Authority"**, right click **Get info**
4. Change **Trust** value to **"Use System Defaults"**

[image]

5. Repeat this for **"Developer ID Certification Authority"** too.

Comment: This worked perfectly. The Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority certificate was in the System keychain.

Comment: Still, I have The same problem please can anyone help to solve this error?

Comment: Have wasted hours, this resolution + [Go to "File" > "Project Settings...", then select "Legacy Build System"] fixed for me (I was trying to build ionic 3 ios app - XCode 10.2). Thanks @Kampai

Answer (score 5):

I have got this issue. I have restarted xcode and tried again, then it works like a charm!

If this problem still persists, then I can Go to Keychain Access, delete all the expired certificates, and add the corresponding valid ones.

Comment: Good answer. Worked perfectly in my case. Also check provisioning profiles whether they might becomes invalid.

Answer (score 3):

It's because the private key that is used for creating the provisioning profile is not installed to your **KeyChain**. I think you just download the provisioning profile directly and archive? You should ask for the private key from the person who create that certificate. And then import to your **KeyChain**. This error will go away.

Comment: I believe i have that added to my keychain.  I'll edit my question to show what my keychain looks like.

Comment: We don't need whether the cert you have is the one you use to create the provisioning profile. I just give you what you should go with based on the error you got. I suggest you delete everything and do it over again.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I actually had a distribution certificate that was set to "**Always Trust**" on Keychain Access which resulted "iOS Missing or Invalid Signature: The bundle is not signed using an Apple Submission Certificate" issue.

Once I changed back to "**System Default**" the problem went away.

Thanks [kampai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3126646/kampai) for pointing me to right way.

Comment: If you see an error like Warning: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer "iPhone Distribution: ╳" check to ensure your certificate is NOT "Always Trust" …thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using old Xcode (like me with xcode 11.3.1 on virtual machine), downloading intermediate apple certificate will help (you can do it at developer.apple.com when adding new cert.), then add it to your keychain by clicking on it.

Answer (score 1):

I got this issue too. And resolve it by updating Dev Key and Distribution Key on KeyChain Access ( Developer give me wrong key). Then I Export Archive and Upload to Itune

Answer (score 1):

Per @Kanak

For Cordova/Ionic,

1. Go to xCode
2. Workspace/Project setting
3. In the dropdown, select Legacy Build System

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue resolved by **resetting the provisioning file** that is by first setting it to automatic and then manually set to appropriate settings. Then cleaned the build and rebuilt and submitted without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you are trying to upload and submit a build created with `xcodebuild` after an Xcode or OS X version update if you haven't installed the latest Xcode components on the your machine or build server (and didn't use the `-runFirstLaunch` parameter).