# Application loader : Itms-90034 error

Tags: certificate, app-store, ipa, application-loader

```
    ERROR ITMS-90034: "Missing or invalid signature. The bundle '24D65G53J4.iPhoneTest' at bundle path 'Payload/EHRS_APP.app' is not signed using an Apple submission certificate."
```

I have this problem, I got certificate from apple still I cant know what is problem

Comment: Check the certificates you are using are valid . Hope this helps you: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19090640/failed-to-submit-app-to-itunes-store)

Comment: Thank you , I will check this

Comment: Hello @Sujania, Still I cant find any wrong in certificate, I have downloaded certificates from apple, and also "Apple Root Certificate Authority" also not not helped me

Comment: Make change in Apple Woldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority certificate from "Always Trust" to "Use the system default". Let me know whether it is working?

Comment: It is showing "This certificate has been revoked" in red. Still not working

Comment: Than create new mobile  provisional certificates and install in keychain access